# How to clear Session in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session, devexpress

I create a `Session["smn"]` when click a button.

I want Session will clear when popup control closed.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

    function ClearSession()
    {
        //clear Session["smn"];
    }

  </script>
```

ASPxPopupControl

```
 <dx:ASPxPopupControl ID="popup1" PopupHorizontalAlign="WindowCenter"  runat="server" 
 ClientInstanceName="popup1"  PopupVerticalAlign="WindowCenter" ShowPinButton="true"    
 ShowCollapseButton="true" CloseAction="CloseButton" AllowDragging="True" Width="800px" Height="600px">
        <ContentCollection>
            <dx:PopupControlContentControl ID="PopupControlContentControl1" runat="server">



            </dx:PopupControlContentControl>
        </ContentCollection>

    <ClientSideEvents CloseButtonClick="ClearSession" />
    </dx:ASPxPopupControl>
```

How can I clear `Session["smn"]` in `ClearSession()` function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you need to clear the session on popup close in your `CloseButtonClick` event, then you can use a hidden button on your page and fire that event using javascript to clear your session like below:

1.Add CSS in your page

> ```
>    <style>.hidden { display: none; }</style>
> ```

2.Add this script

> ```
>    function ClearSession() { document.getElementById("btnHidden").click(); }
> ```

3.Add a hidden control like this one

> ```
>    <asp:Button ID="btnHidden" runat="server" CssClass="hidden" 
>                  OnClick="Button1_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" />
> ```

4.Add this one in your code behind

> ```
>    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { Session["smn"] = null; }
> ```

Now on your control you just need to call the javascript above, pretty much the same as yours:

> ```
>    <ClientSideEvents CloseButtonClick="ClearSession()" />
> ```

Comment: Yes it's a good solution, but - user3107343 - do you understand that session state does not *exist* to JavaScript in your page ?

Comment: -1 to @sh1rts what is your point to say this ? OP didn't ask to use the session in JavaScript. he just wants to clear the session using JavaScript

Answer (score 3):

Session variables are stored at server side. There are lot of way to clear Server Side session side.

Here is one way in which you create ClearSession.ashx (generic handler). To clear server side session state, you call `ClearSession.ashx` from javascript.

```
public class ClearSession : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Session["Date"] = null;
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the server to kill a session variable.

You cannot kill the session with javascript alone. Make an AJAX call to the server and set the variable to `null`.